# How do I extract specific files from Cuckoo Sandbox VM?

Tags: malware, cuckoo

I study about ransomware behavior with cuckoo sandbox. I need to get encrypted files and threatening letter which those made by ransomware, but they exist on my Cuckoo Sandbox VM. How do I extract specific files from its VM?

my environment:
cuckoo sandbox 2.06
Host OS:Ubuntu 18.04
Guest OS:Windows7SP1x86(without guest additions)
VM soft: Virtual Box 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You can get the requiere time to handle your manipulatiuons by:
1- specify a hight number of second  either using command line (ex --timeout 300) or GUI.
2- Force waiting the time out (add --enforce-timeout in the command line) or using the GUI.
3- copy the requiered files in rhe chared folder.
4- to get the displayed message made by he ransomware, you can take screenshot from the host machine.